# Getting an error when doing a POST {{url}}/auth request to generate JWT Token in Postman

Tags: python-3.x, postman, flask-restful

Trying to generate the JWT access token after clicking "send". However the following error occurs:

[image]

Postman logs:

[image]

Environmental Variables:

[image]

The URL looks as to be in the correct format.
Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: In the console, it produces the correct url `http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth` but this resource doesnt exist, so you get 404. Please check the backend code to make sure nothing wrong.

Comment: Yes that was a good place to look. I forgot that I changed the default authentication url path to a customized version. I just commented the line of code out and it fixed it.